# Como armar un diccionario con claves y valores como listas de diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo estos datos llamados *bloquesRestantes* y *bloquesInfoRestante*:

```
bloquesRestantes = ['Articulos', 'Proyectos']
bloquesInfoRestante = {
   "Articulos":[
      {
         "pais":"Peru",
         "indice":"Artículos Publicados de Divulgación Local",
         "fecha_publicacion":"2005-02-04",
         "mapeo":[
            "Pais",
            "Indice",
            "Fecha Publicacion"
         ]
      },
      {
         "pais":"Turquia",
         "indice":"Artículos",
         "fecha_publicacion":"1995-02-04",
         "mapeo":[
            "Pais",
            "Indice",
            "Fecha Publicacion"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "Proyectos":[
      {
         "fecha_inicio":"2005-02-01",
         "codigo_proyecto":"",
         "descripcion":"Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa",
         "mapeo":[
            "Fecha Inicio",
            "Codigo Proyecto",
            "Descripcion",  
         ]
      },
      {
         "fecha_inicio":"2008-08-08",
         "codigo_proyecto":"008",
         "descripcion":"Descripcion test",
         "mapeo":[
            "Fecha Inicio",
            "Codigo Proyecto",
            "Descripcion",  
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Uso esa información y por medio de la funcion zip() mapeo la información con el elemento `mapeo` de la data  `bloquesInfoRestante` de la siguiente forma:

```
listaData = dict()
for i in bloquesRestantes:
  for bloqueInformacion in bloquesInfoRestante[i]:
    resultados = dict(zip(bloqueInformacion['mapeo'], bloqueInformacion.values()))
    listaData[i] = [{k:v for k,v in resultados.items()}]
print(listaData)
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora en la linea donde se encuentra`listaData[i]` lo que intento es que por cada clave del diccionario `bloquesInfoRestante` que son *'Articulos', 'Proyectos'*. poder obtener la información de la lista de  cada uno.

Pero así como lo estoy haciendo solamente estoy obteniendo el ultimo elemento de cada llave de `bloquesInfoRestante` de la siguiente forma:

```
listaData = {
   "Articulos":[
      {
         "Pais":"Turquia",
         "Indice":"Artículos",
         "Fecha Publicacion":"1995-02-04"
      }
   ],
   "Proyectos":[
      {
         "Fecha Inicio":"2008-08-08",
         "Codigo Proyecto":"008",
         "Descripcion":"Descripcion test",
      }
   ],
}
```

Cuando mi intención es obtener los datos así:

```
listaData = {
   "Articulos":[
      {
         "Pais":"Peru",
         "Indice":"Artículos Publicados de Divulgación Local",
         "Fecha Publicacion":"2005-02-04"
      },
      {
         "Pais":"Turquia",
         "Indice":"Artículos",
         "Fecha Publicacion":"1995-02-04"
      }

   ],
   "Proyectos":[
      {
         "Fecha Inicio":"2005-02-01",
         "Codigo Proyecto":"",
         "Descripcion":"Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa",
      }, 
      {
         "Fecha Inicio":"2008-08-08",
         "Codigo Proyecto":"008",
         "Descripcion":"Descripcion test",
      }
   ],
}
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo llegar a obtener la información de esta forma. Espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se quiere eliminar del diccionario la clave `"mapeo"` dentro de cada elemento contenido `"Articulos"` y `"Proyectos"` (`bloquesRestantes`), los diccionarios en `Python` cuentan con un método `pop`.

Para ello hay que iterar los elementos contenidos tanto en `"Articulos"` y `"Proyectos"` (`bloquesRestantes`), teniéndose en cuenta que, al iterarse los elementos en un diccionario no mantienen siempre el mismo orden.

En este caso, como la estructura mostrada siempre cuenta con la clave `"mapeo"` se puede crear unos indice con `enumerate` para tal fin.

> Si en caso la clave `"mapeo"` no existiera... se incluye una condicional para verficar que el diccionario interno en cada elemento de `"Articulos"` y `"Proyectos"` (son listas) exista dicha clave para aplicar el método `pop`

Adicionalmente se requiere reemplazar las claves `"codigo_proyecto"` a `""Codigo Proyecto""` para ellos emplea el método `replace` y title.

> Con respecto a reemplazar las claves voy a decantarme por el método `pop`... esto implicaría usar un bucle `while` por la longitud del diccionario cambiaría conforme se vaya iterando, en tal sentido un bucle `for` tiraría error.

```
data_a_limpiar = 'mapeo'
data_lista = bloquesInfoRestante.copy() # para preservar nuestra data cruda

for bloquesRestantes, data_cruda in data_lista.items():
    for id, _ in enumerate(data_cruda):
        # verificamos si exite la clave "mapeo" para eliminarla
        if data_a_limpiar in data_lista[bloquesRestantes][id].keys():
            data_lista[bloquesRestantes][id].pop(data_a_limpiar, None)
        
        # Se emplea un bucle while porque la longitud del diccionario cambia 
        index = 0
        claves = list(data_lista[bloquesRestantes][id].keys())
        while index < len(claves):
            clave = claves[index]
            nueva_clave = clave.replace('_',' ').title()
            data_lista[bloquesRestantes][id][nueva_clave] = data_lista[bloquesRestantes][id].pop(clave)
            index += 1
            

# Resultado
print(data_lista)
"""
{
   "Articulos": [
      {
         "Indice": "Artículos Publicados de Divulgación Local",
         "Fecha Publicacion": "2005-02-04",
         "Pais": "Peru"
      },
      {
         "Indice": "Artículos",
         "Pais": "Turquia",
         "Fecha Publicacion": "1995-02-04"
      }
   ],
   "Proyectos": [
      {
         "Codigo Proyecto": "",
         "Descripcion": "Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa",
         "Fecha Inicio": "2005-02-01"
      },
      {
         "Descripcion": "Descripcion test",
         "Codigo Proyecto": "008",
         "Fecha Inicio": "2008-08-08"
      }
   ]
}
"""
```

> Al tener datos anidados hasta el tercer nivel, la solución expuesta es de complejidad `O(n3)` en tal sentido, no se aconseja para volúmenes grandes de datos... puede trabajarse mejor con clusters o dividiendo los datos para facilitar su procesamiento mediante computación distribuida.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero no busco eliminar mapeo, de hecho lo uso para sacar como key en la nueva data, lo que quiero es que en la linea donde esta `listaData[i]` sacar los valores de Proyectos y Articulos pero solo puedo obtener el ultimo.

Comment: En la pregunta mencionas `...Cuando mi intención es obtener los datos así:... listaData = { "Articulos":[ { "Pais":"Peru",...` el código que he expuesto da lo mismo. En todo caso, si su pregunta es una "asignación" y se le ha pedido que esta sea resuelta con un método específico, sugiero que lo indique en su pregunta, así lograrás obtener la respuesta que vos necesita.

Comment: Efectivamente, deseo obtener los datos como lo puse en mi pregunta, pero si se fija bien, la key es  `listaData = { "Articulos":[ { "Pais":"Peru", ..` y ya no `pais` o  `fecha_publicacion` sino `Fecha Publicacion` para eso uso el elemento mapeo, pero eso ya lo tengo, mi pregunta va mas bien se da que en base a el  `zip()` que hago  yo pueda obtener los datos  de forma similar a lo que obtiene usted, lo que cambia es la key de cada elemento. No importa el método con el que se pueda obtener esto

Comment: Ok, ya vi que necesitas las claves como si fueran `"títulos"` voy a incluirlo en mi respuesta pero hay que tener presente que la solución pasaría de complejidad `O(n2)` a `O(n3)`